# Zoom кастомного View внутри RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, customview, zoom

Я хочу увелитить мое текущее CustomView, которое находится в RecyclerView. Для этого я настроил onScale в классе этого View

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Scale factor: " + detector.getScaleFactor());

        ZOOM *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        ZOOM = (Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(ZOOM, 5.0f)));

        Log.d(TAG, "ZOOM: " + ZOOM);

        wasZoom = true;

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getParent();
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
```

И, соответсвенно, после нотификации адаптера происходит изменение в onMeasure данного активити

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure((int) ((float) widthMeasureSpec * ZOOM), heightMeasureSpec);
    invalidate();
}
```

Однако когда view в RecyclerView несколько, то логи scale фактор ведет себя не очень реалистично, почти всего показывая scale factor = 1, что, скорее всего, связано с тем, что после notifyDataSetChanges адапьтер сбрасывает значание scaleFactor к 0. Кроме того, из-за прокрутки view почти невозможно отскейлить данные view. Как это исправить и сделать плавный zoom?